# Как убрать задний план в QScrollBar?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qss, scrollbar

Как в `styleSheet` убрать эту белую сетку в `QScrollBar`?

[image: Текст]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пожалуйста, **всегда предоставляйте минимальный пример** !!!

Вот эта строка сделает то что вы хотите:

```
QScrollBar:vertical {
    ...
    background: transparent;         /*   убрать эту белую сетку в скроллбаре                 
    ...
}
```

поэкспериментируйте с таблицей стилей `QScrollBar`

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import  QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QAction, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QScrollArea
from threading import Thread


class DragNDropWindow(QWidget): #, Thread):                      # ?
    def __init__(self, parent=None):                             
        super(DragNDropWindow, self).__init__(parent)            

        self.setStyleSheet("""
QWidget {        
    border: none;        
}      

/* QScrollArea ----------------------------------------------------- */
QScrollArea QWidget QWidget:disabled {
    background-color: #232629;          
}

/* QScrollBar ------------------------------------------------------ */

QScrollBar:vertical {
/*    background-color: #foo;             попробуйте раскомментировать, убрав строку ниже     */
    background: transparent;         /*   убрать эту белую сетку в скроллбаре                 */
    width: 16px;
    margin: 16px 2px 16px 2px;       
    border: 0px solid #31363B;       /* попробуйте заменит на это: border: 1px solid #31363B; */
    border-radius: 4px;
}


QScrollBar::handle:vertical {
    background-color: #4D545B;     
    border: 1px solid #31363B;
    min-height: 8px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

QScrollBar::handle:vertical:hover {
    background-color: #179AE0;      
    border: 1px solid #179AE0;
    border-radius: 4px;
    min-height: 8px;
}

QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {
    margin: 3px 0px 3px 0px;
    border-image: url(icons/up_arrow_disabled.png);
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: top;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}

QScrollBar::add-line:vertical {
    margin: 3px 0px 3px 0px;
    border-image: url(icons/down_arrow_disabled.png);
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: bottom;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}

QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:hover,
QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical:on {
    border-image: url(icons/up_arrow.png);
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: top;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}

QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:hover,
QScrollBar::add-line:vertical:on {
    border-image: url(/icons/down_arrow.png);
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: bottom;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}

QScrollBar::up-arrow:vertical,
QScrollBar::down-arrow:vertical {
    background: none;                   
}

QScrollBar::add-page:vertical,
QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical {
    background: none;                
}
        """)

        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.Window | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)         

        self.background = QLabel(self)                          
        bpixmap = QPixmap('lena-removebg-preview.png')         
        self.background.setPixmap(bpixmap)
        self.background.show()

        with open('test.txt') as mindList:                     
            mindList = mindList.read()
        minds = mindList.split(sep='@@\n@@')

        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addStretch(1)
        vbox.setSpacing(15)

        for i in minds:
            label = QLabel(self)
            label.setText(i)
            label.setFixedWidth(420)
            label.setStyleSheet('''
                font: 10pt "Jack Brusher(RUS BY LYAJKA)";
                background-color: #778899;
                border-radius: 5px;
                color: #FFFFE0;
                padding: 15;
            ''')
            label.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.ActionsContextMenu)
            action = QAction("Скрыть текст", self)
            action.triggered.connect(label.hide)
            label.addAction(action)
            vbox.addWidget(label)

        label.setWordWrap(True)                                            
        self.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.ActionsContextMenu)
        action2 = QAction("Показать текст", self)
        action2.triggered.connect(label.show)
        self.addAction(action2)

        self.scrollarea = QScrollArea(self)
        self.scrollarea.resize(self.background.width(), self.background.height())
        self.scrollarea.setWidgetResizable(True)

        area = QWidget()
        area.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)               
        area.setLayout(vbox)
        self.scrollarea.setWidget(area)

        ''' УБРАЛ
        self.scrollarea.setStyleSheet("""
            QScrollBar:vertical {              

                background: red;
                width: 7px;
                margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
            }
        """)
        '''

        self.resize(self.background.width(), self.background.height())
        self._old_pos = None

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self._old_pos = event.pos()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self._old_pos = None

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if not self._old_pos:
            return
        delta = event.pos() - self._old_pos
        self.move(self.pos() + delta)


class MyWin(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 220)
        self.setWindowTitle('MyWin')
        self.dd = DragNDropWindow(self)      
        self.dd.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWin()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]