# Как убрать фон QScrollBar

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qss, qscrollarea

Столкнулся с затруднением: при попытке сделать фон QScrollBar прозрачным он всё равно остаётся видимым. Я так же пробовал [этот способ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1129525/525222), однако, безрезультатно. Подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так?

**SSExample.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    """Doc."""

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """Doc."""
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        centralwidget = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralwidget)
        main_box = QGridLayout(centralwidget)

        self.city_scrollArea = QScrollArea(self)
        self.city_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.city_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.city_widget)
        self.city_scrollArea.setWidget(self.city_widget)
        self.city_scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        main_box.addWidget(self.city_scrollArea)

        for i in range(20):
            pb = QPushButton(f"push_button_{i}")
            self.city_layout.addWidget(pb)

        self.setStyleSheet("""

QMainWindow {
    background: blue;
}
QScrollBar:vertical {
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    background: transparent;
    width: 8px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
QScrollBar::handle:vertical {
    background: transparent;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    min-height: 0px;
    border-image: url("resources/images/assets/div_animation_0.png") 0 0 0 0;
}
QScrollBar::add-line:vertical {
    height: 0px;
    subcontrol-position: bottom;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {
    height: 0 px;
    subcontrol-position: top;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}

#Scroll_Area {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: transparent;
}

""")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        centralwidget = QWidget(self)
        centralwidget.setObjectName('centralwidget')                      # +
        self.setCentralWidget(centralwidget)
        main_box = QGridLayout(centralwidget)

        self.city_scrollArea = QScrollArea(self)
        self.city_scrollArea.setObjectName('city_scrollArea')
        
        self.city_widget = QWidget(self)
        self.city_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.city_widget)
        self.city_scrollArea.setWidget(self.city_widget)
        self.city_scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        main_box.addWidget(self.city_scrollArea)

        for i in range(20):
            pb = QPushButton(f"push_button_{i}")
            self.city_layout.addWidget(pb)

        self.setStyleSheet("""
#centralwidget {
    background: #609772;
}        
   
/* ===================== QScrollBar ======================= */
QScrollBar:vertical {
    background: #609772;
    width: 15px;
    margin: 0px 3px 0px 3px;    
    border: 1px transparent #2A2929;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
QScrollBar::handle:vertical {
    background-color: #609772;                    
    min-height: 5px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-image: url("ball.png") 0 0 0 0;      /* <---- установите свое изображение */ 
}
QScrollBar::sub-line:vertical {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    height: 0px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: top;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
QScrollBar::add-line:vertical {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    height: 0px;
    width: 10px;
    subcontrol-position: bottom;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
QScrollBar::up-arrow:vertical, QScrollBar::down-arrow:vertical {
    background: none;
}
QScrollBar::add-page:vertical, QScrollBar::sub-page:vertical {
    background: none;
}
""")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**ball.png**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]